# Are articles exactly even required for English language?

Tags: grammar, articles

My native language is Finnish that doesn't exactly have articles. It has never felt like limitation. This why it has been hard to understand why there is need for the articles. I feel like I'm just using huge amount of time for trying to remember grammar rules. Like when to use articles and when to not while not gaining any benefit from it.

EDIT:

Obviously, I understand that the rules say they must be there (Because I already said so). My question is this:

- What bang do speakers get for their buck in English, for using articles—when so many languages don't have them at all?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Finnish, but I know Norwegian has the equivalent of a definite article in the "-en" suffix.  I wonder if Finnish doesn't do something similar.

Comment: @HotLicks, my understanding is Finnish is wildly different from any other language except possibly Hungarian and some central Asian languages. It's not even an Indo-European language, so certainly not a Germanic/Scandinavian one.

Comment: Forget grammar rules. Try listening and remembering examples. All languages present difficulties to learners. I am sure Finnish has things that might seem the same way to English speakers.

Comment: English doesn't have vowel harmony.  This has never seemed like a limitation to me.  Different languages have different features.  Not all of them are entirely necessary.  Natural languages, like naturally selected life forms, have extraneous and inefficient characteristics. Will English speakers stop using articles?  Not in our lifetime.  Should you try speaking English without articles?  Sure, go ahead and try.  It may work.

Comment: There's a lot of difference between "We went to see _Queen_" and "We went to see the Queen".  And between "He's got cold" and "He's got a cold". And "There was a toast" and "There was toast". And "They weighed the anchor" and "They weighed anchor".

Comment: And you’ve come onto a site that is for serious students of the English language to complain that English is difficult and has concepts not found in other languages? Remind me to go onto the French site and complain about gender, or the German site and complain about case, or the Italian site and complain about the subjective, and doesn’t one of the Scandinavian languages have a concept of two of something? Oh dear.

Comment: But the question is not invalid. I understand it, amidst the griping and complaining, as "What difference does the presence of articles make?" Edwin Ashworth above made a good set of examples, for instance.

Comment: @David I thought OP was just asking why articles were so important for communicatipn in English when they don't exist in the other language they speak?

Comment: @Araucaria — I answered his question in the general sense that different languages allow different subtleties and shades of meaning, even though other languages manage without. If he doesn’t understand what articles bring to a language, he should be asking on English Language Learners or read an English primer. This site is supposed to be for questions at a higher level — check the Tour.

Comment: @David I don't believe you answered so much as had an outcry and subsequently complained. Were you actually attempting to point him in the right direction you'd have provided him with the link and information about the English Language Learners SE.

Comment: There are many features of the world’s languages that are not really necessary. Does vowel harmony add anything to Finnish? Does having fifteen cases? Does telicity add anything that you couldn’t easily infer from context? Does consonant gradation serve any purpose but to complicate things for learners? Finnish could easily do without all these entirely, but they’re part and parcel of what Finnish currently **is** – it wouldn’t be Finnish without them. Same with articles, strong verbs, stress-based derivation, subject-verb inversion and so on in English.

Comment: @psosuna — It’s not my job to point him to ELL, which may not even accept this sort of question. He’s the one that is ranting about wasting his time, and he’s the one who should have read the label on the site. There are certain things about the different ways languages work that one discovers early in one’s first encounter. Accept it and get stuck in.

Comment: @David When it's everyone's job it's no one's job, is that it? It may not be your job and I never called it such. Just saying that if your aim was to be actually helpful that's what you could/would have done, but didn't. Anyway, I'm not up to arguing further with someone on the internet. I'm guilty of the same, if we're being honest. :-)

Comment: @psosuna — Be careful. Look at my record of giving links to the Help and Tour on my main SE site (Biology). I've done it a lot here as well and been told off for recommending ELL (which I'm not a member of) because the Q was unsuitable. (As it happens I was on my phone when I made that comment, so it was almost impossible to find the link and copy it.)

Comment: @David I've been reprimanded in the past, too, for directing to ELL, but sometimes I wonder specifically how questions about basic grammar don't fit the scope... Oh well. Such is life.

Comment: @psosuna Why don't you give this a reopen vote?

Comment: Articles aid with precision. Sometimes the difference between **a** thing, **that** thing, and **the** thing can be important.

Comment: @Araucaria Because I do have problems with the tone of the question rather than the question itself. It's clear OP means to understand why they exist, but it does come across as speaking from a "higher place," and I would maybe vote to reopen if it didn't have those undertones.

Answer (score 1):

English usage has grown up around articles and their use. Articles currently serve to distinguish between various synonyms and nouns in general. They serve the purpose and would be tough to replace. In Scotland they may speak English with a great economy of articles but I do not know why.

You might tell us how in Finnish you would distinguish between going to see *Queen*, the band, and going to see *the* Queen, the ruler of England, as the comments suggest. Or even explain how one could aspire to be *a* queen vs *the* Queen. This is not to be accusatory or snarky, I have great respect for the Nordic languages but cannot imagine how it would be done without articles or similar syntactic furniture. I imagine a fleet of idioms coming into play perhaps.

Comment: Well, the difference between seeing Queen (the band) and the Queen (of the UK) would be very easy in Finnish: one is _Queen_, the other is _kuningatar_. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet most bands have ‘the’ as in ‘the Beatles’, ‘the Rolling Stones’.  ‘Queen’ without the article was a style choice.

Comment: "the" in band names died out in the Seventies.  There's probably an interesting question/answer there.